# Unity transform an object to a local Vector3 not global

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to instanstiate an object and update its position from what where I am spawning it. I am spawning this object on the parets + 10x position.

```
Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position + new Vector3(10, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

When I do this, it nearly does what I want it to, however it will spawn the object and give it 10x on the global position not local, where it was spawned from. **After looking online, I tried:**

```
transform.localposition
```

However that gave me the error of *"CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'localpositon'"*

Would anyone know what I am missing when it comes to instanstiating something on a local Vector3?

**Edit*** Thinking of the terminology, I guess the result that I am expecting is for the object I am creating to be pivoted around a certain point when spawned in, not just rotated and position on the Vector3 coordinates.

This point being the spawn location in the world, which is just parent world location + child location.

Comment: `localPosition` is mentioned however does this object have a parent? If not then keep note that `localPosition` would be the same, unless the rotation of the object is something other than `Quaternion.identity`.

Answer (score 1):

When a name does not work try to use auto complete (visual studio) or verify with the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) that it is spelled correctly and that it exists.

The field you seek is called `localPosition` (`P` is capital).

Comment: So how would I add an extra vector3 position but on the local not global? The spelling mistake yea that's fixed

Comment: you set absolute position in `Instantiate` then after it's instantiated you `transform.localPosition += new Vector3(10, 0, 0);` However if you are using `Vector3(10, 0, 0)` repeatedly you may want to store it as a constant. Usually you keep a prefab inactive by default then set it active after modifying all the properties you want it to start off with.

Comment: Also note that localPosition depends on rotation. You mentioned nothing about rotation so you might not even need to use local position

Comment: Rotation isn't a problem right now due to the objects that I have created thankfully. But I see what the coordinate problem is. The object that instanstiates objects is a child of a parent object, and that child is in 0,0,0 position of the parent, however I needed the parents world coordinates.

Comment: Actually I might need the roation of current objects that is spawning in objects. How would that be done. Would I have to somehow save current rotation and pass it on to the object I am trying to spawn?

Comment: Based on the information I am being given now I can see it's not clear what the objective of this post is. My answer corrects `'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'localpositon'"` but in terms of the rest of your problem it is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is related. I can rotate an object however it will still spawn not where it's meant to spawn, it still spawns in world positions. I'm trying to see why, but an object that is rotated by 90 or -90 comes back as 0.7071068 or -0.7071068. 

To me, clearly this localPosition doesn't seem to work or something else isn't working, when in the scene my object says 90 but script returns 0.7071068 rotation.

Comment: Please add all these details to the question so that we can assist you.

Comment: Updated the question. I think I needed different terminology to explain my idea, what I don't understand